# mark/reset exception during getAudioInputStream()

Tags: java, audio, java-7, javasound

I posted a fix of a problem (explained below) but haven't been able to confirm if it solves the problem. Would someone with Java 7 try the out the following Applet and report back? It would be MUCH appreciated.

[AudioMixerDemo](http://www.hexara.com/VSL/AudioMixerDemoWarOfWorlds.htm)

The problem that was reported to me was that the top row of buttons which require the load of a sound clip from a jarred resource are not working. The error points to the line where the audio file is being read and says a "mark/reset" I/O exception is being thrown.

This code works for Java 6 is not working for Java 7. The offending statement follows:

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
    AudioMixer.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName));
```

The inner area returns an `InputStream`, and I think that is where the "markability" issue arises. The issue was reported at [Oracle's bug database as a backwards compatibility problem](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7095006), but given a low priority.

I have recoded the above as follows:

```
URL url = AudioMixer.class.getResource(fileName);
AudioInputStream ais =  AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
```

There is nothing in the AudioSystem API that mentions that this method will throw "mark/reset" I/O exceptions. So, I am hopeful. But I haven't been able to confirm this!

Comment: *"The issue was reported at Oracle's bug database as a backwards compatibility problem, but given a low priority."*  What bug ID/URL?

Comment: BTW - AFAIU the ability to support mark/reset in an URL depends on the server.  Some support it, some don't.  A sure fire way to guarantee a mark(able)/reset(able) input stream is to read the entire `byte[]` then pass that to the constructor of a `ByteArrayInputStream`.  Oh, and I don't have Java 7 installed so cannot test your applet, sorry.  (I tried J7 a while ago and when it failed with my DukeBox app. I uninstalled it in disgust - will wait for a less buggy variant.)

Comment: How do I mark this as "solved"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java 7 user who reported the problem has contacted me and given a thumbs up. So I am presuming the diagnosis and fix of the backwards compatibility problem are correct, and no longer am seeking testers (unless you are just interested in checking out the AudioMixer).