# where to place sound files relative to a java project?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

This is the first time I've implemented sounds but I can't figure out where to actually place the sounds to play them. I am using Eclipse as my IDE and I've put my sounds in a folder called sounds.

The following code is what I've used to create one of the audioclip objects:

```
private final String background = "." + slash + "sounds" + slash + "background.wav";

main(....){
    try {
        backgroundClip = Applet.newAudioClip(new File(background).toURI().toURL());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't hear anything. When I remove the `try/catch` I get an error saying that it is unable to find the file. I placed my sound folder in both `/src` and `/bin` but neither can find it. where do I put it?

Comment: 1) `String background = "." + slash + ..`  If the value of `slash` is `/` it is wrong.  If the value is `System.getProperty("file.separator")` it should be called `separator` (or something similar).  But `File` has constructors that can do all that for you. 2) Since Java 1.3, the J2SE has offered that `javax.sound.sampled` API.  Use that instead of an `AudioClip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base for your project is the level above the `src` folder. So using `.` will put you at your project folder.

Basically,

```
. = project_root

./src = default_package
./src/packagename = inside the package named "packagename"

./sounds/background.wav = a .wav file in the sounds folder, in the project_root
```

Using your current path, you need to put your `.wav` file in the `sounds` folder in the `project_root`.

The path will end up being `project_root/sounds/background.wav`.

Comment: What? isn't the "." refers to the current folder where the execution is going on?

Comment: yes. The execution occurs at `project_base`. I've spent days trying to figure this out before, and these were my results.

Answer (score 2):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462029/loading-jpgs-into-swing-apps/8462092#8462092) to understand why application resources should be obtained by `URL` obtained from `getResource()`, rather than a `File` converted to an `URL`.

Comment: Concur. And with Java 7, it's even more important to use URL in your getResource(). I ran into a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091967/mark-reset-exception-during-getaudioinputstream